# XCode ARC allows release

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, automatic-ref-counting, memory-leaks

It is very strange that ARC allows release operations but doesn't allow retain operations. As far I know, all of them are forbidden. And my app crashes due to memory leaks. Why ARC is not working properly?

[image]

Comment: ARC doesn't allow to release and autorelease objects. Are you sure that you use it correct?

Comment: Without knowing what you have done, we can't possibly know.  Probably a mess of erroneous compiler flags.

Comment: I have checked flags and also I have checked if arc is enabled with this code "#if  __has_feature(objc_arc)" and it approves the arc is enabled

Comment: That check tests if ARC is *available*.  It does not check if it is *enabled*

Comment: Look what error you will get if ARC is enabled http://subhb.org/2011/11/27/objective-c-memory-management-with-automatic-reference-counting-arc/

Comment: I know arc does not let me use release but it doesn't give me that error now

Comment: Have you cleaned your project and restarted Xcode, and it still shows up this way?

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the line

```
[anaView retain];
```

Then `XCode` is surely going to point error to

```
[anaView release];
```

XCode doesn't show all the errors at the same time.

**Side Note:**

```
[anaView release];
[anaView retain];
```

Looks strange to me. I mean first `release` and then `retain`; what's the purpose for that ?

Comment: no purpose, just to show the problem and if I delete retain Xcode does not give an error